# Is it possible to access environment variables without the '$' in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, alias

This may seem pretty trivial but I am a novice in bash scripting and I could not find the answer elsewhere.

I have [mplayer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MPlayer) installed on ubuntu 13.04 and I am using it to stream internet radio stations. Normally you need to provide the ip as argument for that:

```
mplayer http://176.31.113.37:8080
```

I have created an aliases file in root `.bash_aliases` where I have the following:

```
export SOMA="http://173.239.76.147:8090"
export FRESH="http://176.31.113.37:8080"
```

Now I can play the radio using only the station name: `mplayer $FRESH`.
I was wondering is it possible to get rid of the `$` sign also to use the command `mplayer FRESH` for example.

Thanks!

Comment: No. That's how the shell knows whether you're typing a literal string or a variable that should be expanded.

Comment: You **can** technically get to the value without using `$` (e.g. by using a `set | grep` construct), but it won't make your command line simpler. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SirAthos There is no hidden reason besides what I have posted. I guess I was looking for an `alias` actually but not being familiar with bash scripting I did not know about it. Thanks any way

Comment: just to address the original question: how is the shell going to decide, whether it (`FRESH`) is a literal string or a variable? this is a horrible idea.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath the same way it decides whether a word is a literal string or a glob. Arguably, that was also a horrible idea.

Comment: You can also do it by using indirection, as I demonstrated below.

Comment: You can't do this in bash: however, zsh has the concept of *global aliases* that you can use anywhere in the command line: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_8.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using variables you need the `$` to expand it.  I would do this with aliases though, not variables.  Consider something like this:

```
alias mpsoma='mplayer http://192.168.1.1:8090'
```

Then just type `mpsoma` to run the full command.

Comment: Yes I guess I was also looking for something like this, but being a n00b I could not figure it out by myself. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can do this; you just need a function with built-in indirection. (In case you don't know, *indirection* is accessing a value through its name instead of through its value. In Bash, this is done by [preceding the variable name with a `!`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection) in the parameter expansion.)

```
##
# Expand variables passed as arguments, otherwise just invoke mplayer normally.
#
mplayer() {
    local first=${!1:-"$1"} # Expand to the indirection of $1 if it exists,
                            # otherwise expand to the value of "$1"
    shift # Drop the 1st parameter. With enough focus, I could probably make this
          # do the indirection on every positional parameter, but it's Friday.
    command mplayer "$first" "$@"
}
```

If you put `echo` before the `command mplayer` part you can see what it's doing:

```
$ mplayer my name is dug
command mplayer my name is dug
$ my=your
$ mplayer my name is dug
command mplayer your name is dug
$ my=our mplayer my name is dug # You can even do in-place export assignment
command mplayer our name is dug
$ echo $my
your
```

Answer (score 2):

I found your idea pretty nice so I thought about how this could be solved in another way. What came into my mind was to setup a function inside your `~/.bashrc`. The function will be executable like any other command:

```
# Give the function a nice name - "mplayer" could be problematic
radio()
{
    # Validate the number of parameters passed to our function
    (( $# != 1 )) && {
        printf "%s\n" "Please provide exactly one stream. Quitting."
        return 1
    }

    local stream_alias stream_uri

    # Assign the first parameter to a local variable
    stream_alias="$1"

    # Assign uris to a variable dependent on the value of the
    # parameter passed to the function
    case "$stream_alias" in
        fresh)
            stream_uri="http://176.31.113.37:8080"
        ;;

        soma)
            stream_uri="http://173.239.76.147:8090"
        ;;

        *)
            printf "%s\n" "Unknown stream. Quitting."
            return 1
        ;;
    esac

    mplayer "$stream_uri" && {
        printf "%s\n" "Playing radio station «${stream_alias}@${stream_uri#*\/\/}»."
    }

    return 0
}
```

This will give you the following results:

```
$ radio fresh
Playing radio station «fresh@176.31.113.37:8080».

$ radio soma
Playing radio station «soma@173.239.76.147:8090».

$ radio stream1
Unknown stream. Quitting.
```

Although there is room for improvement - like putting the uris and/or station names into (associative) arrays and maybe adding other features - I think you get the idea As an alternative, in cases where you don't want to put the function inside your `.bashrc` maybe because you want it to be available to all users, just use a little script and place it at a location which is in each users `$PATH` (of course you can add a path to it). I use `/usr/local/bin` for that purpose.

```
$ cat radio
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Validate the number of parameters passed to our script
(( $# != 1 )) && {
    printf "%s\n" "Please provide exactly one stream. Quitting."
    exit 1
}

_mplayerStream()
{
    local stream_alias stream_uri

    # Assign the first parameter passed to the function
    # to a local variable
    stream_alias="$1"

    # Assign uris to a variable dependent on the value of the
    # parameter passed to the function
    case "$stream_alias" in
        fresh)
            stream_uri="http://176.31.113.37:8080"
        ;;

        soma)
            stream_uri="http://173.239.76.147:8090"
        ;;

        *)
            printf "%s\n" "Unknown stream. Quitting."
            exit 1
        ;;
    esac

    mplayer "$stream_uri" && {
        printf "%s\n" "Playing radio station «${stream_alias}@${stream_uri#*\/\/}»."
    }

    return 0
}

_mplayerStream "$1"

$ radio soma
Playing radio station «soma@173.239.76.147:8090».
```

A really nice feature I could imagine would be tab completion showing a list of available streams defined inside the script.

Comment: +1 This is actually great, thank you. I am glad you managed to answer before my question was put on hold as 'off-topic'. I am using SO for quite a while and I thought I understand the rules by now but it seems I was wrong...

Comment: Tbh in that case I can't quite reenact why it was closed. Maybe rephrasing the question would have been a better alternative in contrast to closing it down.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an alias like this:

```
alias FRESH="mplayer http://176.31.113.37:8080"
```

Then you can just type

```
FRESH
```

Put that line in the file .profile in your login directory and it will be available every time you log in.

Answer (score 0):

Site note: I would use [bash aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29) in your case. You can write for example in your `.bashrc` (or better `.bash_aliases` file if it exists):

```
alias fresh='mplayer http://176.31.113.37:8080'
```

Now you can type `fresh` in your terminal to listen to this internet stream.