# Can I create a reference to a word like "~" references the home directory?

Tags: bash

I want to know if is it possible to make a word, like `drive` work the way `~` works in bash.

For example:
`mkdir ~/Documents/test_dir` makes the folder `/home/user/Documents/test_dir` 
My goal is that:
`mkdir drive/test_dir` makes the folder  `/home/user/Documents/Google-Drive/test_dir`

Comment: I guess not, but `$drive` works.

Comment: Related: [Do global aliases exist in bash? - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/216414/117037)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to access environment variables without the '$' in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873671/is-it-possible-to-access-environment-variables-without-the-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a variable:

```
drive=/home/user/Documents/Google-Drive
```

Then `echo "$drive/test_dir"` prints `/home/user/Documents/Google-Drive/test_dir`